# Open a file relative to python module path

Tags: python, python-2.7

A little bit of an explanation of my situation before my question.

I created a module called foo. foo's location in the file system is

```
/runtime/foo
```

and the script "test.py" which imports foo by using sys.path.append() is located in.

```
/runtime/bar/test.py
```

Foo's structure is as follows

```
foo
    mtr.txt
    __init__.py
    datasources.py
```

I would like a class within datasources.py to open the file mtr.txt.  However,  I am not able to do this without explicting giving a path within datasources.  In this case it would be

```
/runtime/foo/mtr.txt
```

My code will work if I do give it this path,  but this is something that should be doable, but I can't find the answer.

I have tried the following commands within a class in datasources.py.

```
open("mtr.txt")
open("./mtr.txt")
```

and a few other things using the os.path.dirname()

Is there a way to open the file 'mtr.txt' without giving its full path within datasources.py?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pkg_resources`

```
import pkg_resources
data = pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, "mtr.txt")
```

There are more methods provided by this package, check the docs for [Resource Manager API](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api).

Comment: fyi, link is dead.